# Basic 2D maze generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, maze

I am trying to create a basic maze game where players would start at one spot and have another to finish, I am looking for an npm package to generate this maze with the maze walls and start and finish section.

Currently, I've tried a few git projects generating a 2D array, the ones I have tried to use either don't work, either don't generate or have an endpoint.

I have a static 2D array that I've put together to create the rest of the game, I just want to dynamically create a new maze every round.

```
var map = [
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 3],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
];

0 //space
1 //wall
2 //start
3 //end
```

These variables can change as necessary

If anyone has any suggestions on a library to use, I would greatly appreciate it. Or if someone has a suggestion of a different way to generate the map.

Comment: Couldn't you add the end yourself?

Comment: which packages have you tried that dont have an endpoint?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.